# Deleting layer with its source in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, layers, delete, remove, layer-resource

When I remove a layer, I usually don't need the source anymore either. If now using the QGIS `remove layer...` command, the layer, of course, is gone, but the source file remains in the data and has to be deleted separately in case of being obsolete as well.

This can become a quite inconvenient task when e.g. having tested different versions of a model across a longer time period and having hundreds of shapefiles stored in different folders.

Is there any option in QGIS (or by an according Plugin) to remove a layer together with its source? (I couldn't find any option so far)

Thereby, the removal procedure should of consider the following two things:

1. Prompting if the respective source is in use of other layers, in terms of: "Do you want really remove this source. It is also in use of layers x, y,... YES / NO?"
2. It should delete the source completely, i.e. including all auxiliary files (e.g *.cpg*, *.dbf* ... in case of shapefiles).

Comment: How about using temporary layers?

Comment: And if you need your data over a few restarts of QGIS (so temporary layers as @Erik mentioned are not usable), consider using another file format, e.g. a geodatabase in which several geodatasets are stored in one file rather than shapefiles that splits one geodataset up in a maze of twisty little files.